Adjust code that uses timestamp and timedelta: last timestamp of each day must contain a custom timestamp
I'm currently using the code below:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

initial_date = datetime(1996, 11, 21, 0, 0, 0) 
final_date = datetime(2024, 4, 3, 23, 59, 24)   

time_interval = timedelta(minutes=15)

datetimes_list = []

current_date = initial_date
while current_date <= final_date:
    datetimes_list.append(current_date)
    current_date += time_interval

# print(datetimes_list)

I want to adjust it so that at the end of each day (the code currently consider as final timestamp of each day the 23:45's time) to add a new timestamp at the time 23:59:24. How do I do it? I tried to implement it but I have no idea how to do it.

Is the problem that you don't know how to add the extra timestamp, or you don't know how to check if the current timestamp is 11:45?

I didn't understand the reason for the question, but the problem was understanding the logic of solving the problem as a whole, but I managed to resolve it and even wrote a self answer. Thanks!

The reason for my question is that I wanted to understand your actual difficulty.  You said you want to add an extra timestamp at the end of the day.  So I was asking which part of that is the actual problem?  Adding a timestamp, or knowing when it is the end of the day?

Ok, no problem... Anyway I already answered you about this, thanks!

I ended up getting the desired result:
from datetime import datetime, timedelta

initial_date = datetime(1996, 11, 21, 0, 0, 0)
final_date = datetime(2024, 4, 3, 23, 45, 0)  

time_interval = timedelta(minutes=15)

datetimes_list = []

current_date = initial_date
while current_date <= final_date:
    datetimes_list.append(current_date)
    if current_date.time() == datetime(1, 1, 1, 23, 45).time():
        datetimes_list.append(current_date.replace(minute=59, second=24))
    current_date += time_interval

# print(datetimes_list)


If your custom timestamp is less then 00:00:00 - Interval then datetimes_list order is not correct. And your if condition is hard-coded. If time_interval changes, it must be changed too. If time_interval = 17, then your if is wrong. I'll add a solution as a post.

If custom timestamp equals to current_date, then it will be added twice.

@GhorbanM.Tavakoly I tested the code and it worked perfectly. My requirement is as per what I stated in the question, 15 minutes as time interval does not need to be changed because I did not ask for a general case. And about if being hardcoded, well, I don't see a problem with that, but if you want to give a suggestion on how to improve it, I'd appreciate it.

If works for you, then good. The code is small and easy to implement and debug. But in big projects, this assumptions make tomorrow worse.

Here is a working program. In the loop we have current_datetime and next_datetime. If their day value differ, then we are at the end of day. So we can insert custom timestamp. But order and equality of last timestamp and custom timestamp is matter:
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

# all parameters. don't hard-code them in your code body.
initial_datetime = datetime(1996, 11, 21, 0, 0, 0) 
final_datetime = datetime(2024, 4, 3, 23, 59, 24)   
time_interval = timedelta(minutes=15)
custom_timestamp = time(23, 59, 24)

datetimes_list = []
current_datetime = initial_datetime
next_datetime = initial_datetime + time_interval

while current_datetime <= final_datetime:
    if next_datetime.day != current_datetime.day:
        # this is last interval of day.
        custom_datetime = datetime.combine(current_datetime.date(), custom_timestamp)
        if custom_datetime < current_datetime:
            datetimes_list += [custom_datetime, current_datetime]
        elif custom_datetime > current_datetime:
            datetimes_list += [current_datetime, custom_datetime]
        else: # custom_datetime and current_datetime are same. add one.
            datetimes_list.append(current_datetime)
    else:
        datetimes_list.append(current_datetime)
    current_datetime = next_datetime
    next_datetime += time_interval

for ts in datetimes_list:
    print(ts)

And here is the implementation as a generator:
from datetime import datetime, time, timedelta

def timestamps(initial: datetime, final: datetime, interval: timedelta, custom_timestamp: time) -> list[datetime]:
    current = initial
    next_ = initial + interval

    while current <= final:
        if next_.day != current.day:
            # this is last interval of day.
            custom = datetime.combine(current.date(), custom_timestamp)
            if custom < current:
                yield custom
                yield current
            elif custom > current:
                yield current
                yield custom
            else:
                yield current
        else:
            yield current

        current = next_
        next_ += interval

# all parameters. don't hard-code them in your code body.
initial_datetime = datetime(1996, 11, 21, 0, 0, 0) 
final_datetime = datetime(2024, 4, 3, 23, 59, 24)   
time_interval = timedelta(minutes=15)
custom_timestamp = time(23, 59, 24)

for ts in timestamps(initial_datetime, final_datetime, time_interval, custom_timestamp):
    print(ts)

